# Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, symfony4

I'm trying to add a method to a doctrine repository

```
public function getOpenedImport(Uftts $fattura){
    $dql = "SELECT F.importoFattura*C.segnoNumerico - (SELECT SUM(I.importo*C2.segnoNumerico)
                FROM MyAppDomain:Incas I
                INNER JOIN MyAppDomain:Cjcau AS C2 ON C2.codice = I.causale
                WHERE I.annoDocumento = F.annoDocumento AND I.numeroDocumento = F.numeroDocument) 
            FROM MyAppDomain:Uftts F
            INNER JOIN MyAppDomain:Cjcau C ON C.codice = F.causale
            WHERE F.annoDocumento = :annoDocumento AND F.numeroDocumento = :numeroDocumento";

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);

    $query->setParameters(['annoDocumento' => $fattura->getAnnoDocumento(),
                               'numeroDocumento' => $fattura->getNumeroDocumento()]);


        return $query->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

This query if executed on my Sql Server 2008 returns the expected result, but using doctrine i get

> Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'

I can't find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$dql` variable is not valid DQL. I am not sure how to make it valid also.

You can write plain SQL and run

`$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery($query, $params)`

it's a wrapper over PDO, so you will get result like you were performing simple PDO query.